# How best to display the content of a text file in python

Tags: python-2.7

Ok, I am abit of a python beginner. So, forgive me if this question sounds silly.

I have a directory that contains some .txt files as shown in the image below:

[image]

The 1.txt file contains :

```
Lo! I am lost.
```

I want to write a programme that goes through each file in the shakespeare directory and print out the content of the .txt file. Below is a programme I have written but I am not sure how to print out the content of each file. all it prints is the name of each file but how do I really print out the content of each file.

```
def readFromCorpus(path):
    os.chdir(path)
    for fu in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        print fu


readFromCorpus('./trainingData/shakespeare')
```

I am sorry if this is really a silly question. I just need a pointer to what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def readFromCorpus(path):
    os.chdir(path)
    for fu in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        print('\n\n'+fu)
        with open(fu,'r') as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            for line in data:
                print(line.replace('\n',''))
```